# if control in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This query is what I got:

```
var hede = (from customer in _customerRepository.Table
  join source in _sourcedefinitionepository.Table on customer.SourceCode equals source.SourceCode
  select new {Customer = customer, source.SourceName}
```

And then I wrote this:

```
if (agencyName ! = null )
    hede = hede.Where(p => p.Customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName));
```

How can i put the if code into first part of code?

Comment: I mean, yes probably you can, but why?

Comment: If you would put the check for null AgencyName in the Where, then this will be tested once for every element. Wouldn't it be more efficient to test only once for null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way

```
where agencyName  == null || customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName));
```

**Full query**

```
var hede = (from customer in _customerRepository.Table
join source in _sourcedefinitionepository.Table on customer.SourceCode equals source.SourceCode
where agencyName  == null || customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName))
select new {Customer = customer, source.SourceName}
```

**Updated**
Using lamda.

```
var hede = _customerRepository.Table.Join(_sourcedefinitionepository.Table, c => c.SouceCode , s => s.SourceCode,
                (c, s) => new
                {
                    Customer = c, 
                    s.SourceName
                })).Where(p => agencyName  == null || p.Customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName)).ToList();
```

Comment: **Error CS1660**: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: I've just updated my answer from `p => p.Customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName)` to `customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName)` . Please take a look at

Comment: I said... wow, I can use lambda expressions inside `where` clause! Then I went testing. 

Comment: I've just updated my answer with `lamda` version. please take a look at @Şevval Kahraman

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
 var hede = _customerRepository.Table.Join(_sourcedefinitionepository.Table, 
            x => x.SourceCode, 
            y => y.SourceCode, 
            (customer, source) => new { customer, source.SourceName})
            .Where(p => agencyName == null  ||
            (p.customer.Name.Any(f => p.customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName))));
```

**lambda code**

```
var hede =from customer in _customerRepository.Table
                    join source in _sourcedefinitionepository.Table 
                    on customer.SourceCode equals source.SourceCode
            where agencyName == null || customer.Name.Any(f => customer.Name.StartsWith(agencyName))
                    select new { Customer = customer, source.SourceName };
```

Comment: You might want to look at your first query again... There is a difference between `agencyName==null` and `agencyName==""`